# Gridview lines get the same line height as the height of the lines of the parent table

Tags: asp.net, tablerow

I have a table with 3 columns and 15 rows. I've given a line-height of 30px to the rows of the table. The third column spans all the rows and inside it is a div, inside which is my asp.net gridview. When rendering on the browser the lines of the gridview also get set to 30px. What would be the best way to prevent this so that the gridview lines have the default line height?. Here's the CSS and html:

```
.tr-info {line-height:30px}
```

---

```
<table>
  <tr class="tr-info">
    <td>
    </td>
    <td>
    </td>
    <td rowspan="15">
      <div>
        <asp:GridView runat="server" ID="gvPersonalInfo"></asp>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="tr-info">
    <td>
    </td>
    <td>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <!-- And so on with 13 more rows -->
<table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the appropriate [`CssClass`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.style.cssclass.aspx) for the `RowStyle` and `AlternateRowStyle` styles of your `GridView`:

```
.smallRow {
  height: 15px;
}


<rowstyle CssClass="smallRow" />
<alternatingrowstyle CssClass="smallRow" />
```